# I keep getting an ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'red'

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am trying to prompt a user to either input an int or a string. The int works great but whenever I try to input a string, it gives me the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'green' ". I've tried searching for answers but with no luck. Any help would really be appreciated. thanks.

```
One =  "1 = Red"
Two = "2 = Blue"
Three = "3 = Yellow"
Four = "4 = Pink"
Five = "5 = Purple"

#Prints listed colors
print ("*List of Colors below*")
print (One + "\n" + Two + "\n" + Three + "\n" + Four + "\n" + Five)


num1 = str(input('What is your favorite color? You can either choose the number from the list above or enter your own color: '))

if (int(num1) == 1):
    print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Red')
elif (int(num1) == 2):
    print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Blue')
elif (int(num1) == 3):
    print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Yellow')
elif (int(num1) == 4):
    print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Pink')
elif (int(num1) == 5):
    print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Purple')
elif (int(num1) > 6):
    print ('!Please choose numbers between 1-5!')
else:
    print ("You have entered your own color: " + str(num1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't at all make sense to turn 'red' into an integer does it. So the user should not be able to enter their own color or enter in a color. They must enter in a integer, but then there is no point of taking a string input.

```
num1 = int(input('What is your favorite color? Choose a number from above: '))
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is because a string that is not an int can't be cast to an `int`**

---

If clauses work by first evaluating the conditional in the brackets, then executing the nested code if it evaluates to `True`.

So the first thing that runs in your code is:

`if (int(num1) == 1): ...`

Thus, to evaluate the parity of this statement it has to execute:

`int(num1) == 1`

But `int(num1)` isn't undefined if `num1` is a string (like "green"). Thus the code will produce an error. What you need to do is first check if the value `num1` is a string, then use your cases after converting it to a number.

There are many ways to check if this is an integer in python, consider having a look here: https://www.pythonpool.com/python-check-if-string-is-integer/

The final code might look something like:

```
    One =  "1 = Red"
    Two = "2 = Blue"
    Three = "3 = Yellow"
    Four = "4 = Pink"
    Five = "5 = Purple"
    
    #Prints listed colors
    print ("*List of Colors below*")
    print (One + "\n" + Two + "\n" + Three + "\n" + Four + "\n" + Five)
    
    
    num1 = input('What is your favorite color? You can either choose the number from the list above or enter your own color: ')

    if !num1.isnumeric():
        print ("You have entered your own color: " + str(num1))
    elif (int(num1) == 1):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Red')
    elif (int(num1) == 2):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Blue')
    elif (int(num1) == 3):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Yellow')
    elif (int(num1) == 4):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Pink')
    elif (int(num1) == 5):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Purple')
    else (int(num1) > 6):
        print ('!Please choose numbers between 1-5!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to an attempt to convert a non-numeric string to an integer.
You should use the try/except construct:

```
num1 = str(input('What is your favorite color? You can either choose the number from the list above or enter your own color: '))
try:
    if (int(num1) == 1):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Red')
    elif (int(num1) == 2):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Blue')
    elif (int(num1) == 3):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Yellow')
    elif (int(num1) == 4):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Pink')
    elif (int(num1) == 5):
        print ('You chose the the first color from the list, which is: Purple')
    elif (int(num1) > 6):
        print ('!Please choose numbers between 1-5!')
except ValueError:
    print ("You have entered your own color: " + str(num1))
```